# Resize photo to multiple resolution one time

Tags: android, ios, image, photoshop

I'm Currently developing an application for `IOS` devices and also in the mean time I'm making an icon for this application using Photoshop.

However I'm tired every time I'm developing an application i have to resize it for multiple resolution for instance 28x28, 48x48,80x80..etc

Is there a way so i can resize the photo to multiple resolution at once, so i don't have to do it again and again. i tried to look for a solution however i did not find anything about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this website
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

it will generate icons in every dpis for android.

Cheers,

Comment: thank you i will try it, however i'm developing for IOS

Comment: umm, there is an android tag in your question. but anyway.:)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this site : http://makeappicon.com/  .
Here upload your appIcon of size 1024x1024 and it will send you the archived images at your email. 
And it is for both iOS and Android.